# 0 String could not be parsed as XML, joomla administrator is not working

Tags: php, component, xml, jomsocial

0 String could not be parsed as XML, this error is displaying on my joomla administrator and it is not working.

Comment: Can you set error reporting in your configuration.php to `development`? This will hopefully give you more information.

Comment: Yes i have already done that unfortunately nothing happened

Comment: So, any updates? It's very hard to tell what the issue may be. I assume you got this error after installing an extension, so try disabling some of the recently installed extensions

Comment: Yes i have installed jomsocial on my new joomla installation

Comment: So try disabling it! And also ensure you're using the latest version of Joomla (3.7.x)

Comment: Now i am unable to access my administrator area.

Comment: Yes i am using latest version

Comment: No idea then. You've not really provided any helpful information. Maybe check the PHP error logs

Comment: Do you want me to sent you the website link and access?

Comment: Best not as I don't want to mess around with a live site

Answer (score 1):

Update Joomla to the latest version if it's not already on the latest version.

Update third party extensions to the latest versions ([especially JomSocial as older versions can cause this exact error](https://www.ostraining.com/support-forum/joomla-support/0-string-could-not-be-parsed-as-xml/#113071)).